# PL SQL неверный номер

Tags: sql, oracle

Не получается поменять запись таблицы

Числовые данные сформировать из двух последних цифр, добавив к ним слева десятичную точку. Указания:

использовать функцию length(строка_символов) для получения количества символов в переменной строка_символов;
использовать функцию substr(строка_символов, начальная_позиция, длина_подстроки) для получения подстроки, содержащейся в переменной строка_символов;
использовать конкатенацию строк вида ‘.’||строка_символов для добавления символа десятичного разделителя к переменной строка_символов слева;
использовать функцию to_number(строка_символов, ‘.99’) для преобразования строковой переменной строка_символов к числовому типу данных;
использовать курсорный цикл for.

```
DECLARE
CURSOR occupancy_cur IS
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, COMMISSION_PCT, PHONE_NUMBER FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE COMMISSION_PCT IS NULL;
BEGIN
FOR occupancy_rec IN occupancy_cur
LOOP
update EMPLOYEES set COMMISSION_PCT = SUBSTR(occupancy_rec.PHONE_NUMBER, 1, LENGTH(occupancy_rec.PHONE_NUMBER)) WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = occupancy_rec.EMPLOYEE_ID;
END LOOP;
commit;
END;
```

Comment: Ну это всё отлично... а что не работает-то? в чём проблема? какой собственно вопрос?

Comment: @Akina ORA-01722: invalid number Пишет так при компиляции

Comment: Это значит что в числовое поле COMMISSION_PCT вы пытаетесь занести не число. Сделайте select с тем substr что используете и убедитесь что у вас везде возвращаются только числовые данные

Comment: @Mike
Добавил изменения 
`DECLARE
CURSOR occupancy_cur IS
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, COMMISSION_PCT, PHONE_NUMBER FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE COMMISSION_PCT IS NULL;
BEGIN
FOR occupancy_rec IN occupancy_cur
LOOP
UPDATE EMPLOYEES SET COMMISSION_PCT = TO_NUMBER('(‘.’||SUBSTR(occupancy_rec.PHONE_NUMBER, 2, -(LENGTH(occupancy_rec.PHONE_NUMBER))))', '99') WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = occupancy_rec.EMPLOYEE_ID;
END LOOP;
commit;
END; `

Comment: Если ошибка сохраняется смотрите сами данные, может в них что то не так или substr что то не то берет. Помочь вам не видя ваших данных невозможно. И это просто вопрос отладки, смотреть данные, разбираться где они не числовые. И имейте ввиду, у оракла может быть свое мнение по поводу десятичного разделителя, не факт что он у вас точку принимает, может ему запятая нужна. сделайте просто `select to_number('1.99') from DUAL` убедитесь что так он отрабатывает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убедитесь, что преобразование работает, как описано в задании:

```
select employee_id, phone_number, 
    to_number ('.'||substr (phone_number, -2), 
               'FMD99', 'nls_numeric_characters=''.,''') pct
from hr.employees e
where commission_pct is null
/

EMPLOYEE_ID PHONE_NUMBER                PCT
----------- -------------------- ----------
        100 515.123.4567         ,67       
        101 515.123.4568         ,68       
[...]
        206 515.123.8181         ,81       

72 rows selected.
```

Потом написать анонимный блок PL/SQL не составит труда:

```
declare
    cursor cur is 
        select rowid, phone_number, 
            to_number ('.'||substr (phone_number, -2), 
                       'FMD99', 'nls_numeric_characters=''.,''') pct
        from hr.employees
        where commission_pct is null;
    type currows is table of cur%rowtype;
    cr currows;
begin 
    open cur;
    fetch cur bulk collect into cr;
    close cur;
    forall i in indices of cr 
        update hr.employees set commission_pct = cr(i).pct
        where rowid = cr(i).rowid;
    dbms_output.put_line ('Updated '||sql%rowcount||' rows.');    
end;
/
```

> Updated 72 rows.